# Unable to deploy updateserver for site module

Tags: module, update, server, extension-update

Joomla! does not recognize my module update, so I decided to create a blank module to see if it suffered the same issue -- it did.

**When I search for updates my mod_extension is not visible in the list for available updates.**

Here are my files:

test_extension.xml:

```
<updates>
    <update>
        <name>extension name</name>
        <description>extension description</description>
        <element>mod_extension</element>
        <type>module</type>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <infourl title="Local Info Page">http://updates.local/info.html</infourl>
        <downloads>
            <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">http://updates.local/mod_extension.zip</downloadurl>
        </downloads>
        <tags>
            <tag>stable</tag>
        </tags>
        <maintainer>local tester</maintainer>
        <maintainerurl>http://updates.local</maintainerurl>
        <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.[0123456789]" />
    </update>
</updates>
```

And my mod_extension.xml:

```
<extension type="module" version="3.5" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>mod_extension</name>
    <author>examplename</author>
    <creationDate>December 2019</creationDate>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see License.txt</license>
    <authorEmail>info@example.org</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.example.org</authorUrl>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <updateservers>
        <server type="extension" priority="1" name="mod_extension">http://updates.local/test_extension.xml</server>
    </updateservers>
    <files>
        <filename module="mod_extension">mod_extension.php</filename>
    </files>
</extension>
```

Edit:
Joomla does not show the update.
XML File & Zip File are accessible by URL.

Comment: When you say it's `not updating`, what do you mean by this? It's not detecting the update? It's showing an error when trying to update the file?

Comment: yes - i've cleared the cache already - xml file and zip file are accessible

Comment: Which one is it though? What do you mean by `it's not updating`?

Comment: i've edited my question. When i search for updates my mod_extension is not visible in the list for available updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a client element in your updater xml:

```
<client>site</client>
```

Joomla seems to take the admin as the default.

I tried out your xml and found that joomla was indeed finding the xml file ok and even inserting a record into the #__updates table. However because your module is a site module and the update xml didn't have the client element there, it wasn't matching the update to your extension.

When I added the client element it worked fine. (Although you may need to clear the cache to get it to look for that update again).